# IOS Cordova/Phonegap offline video source tag not working

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, video, html5-video

On IOS When I download some video using cordova filetransfer plugin it doesn't plays(absolute url like: file:///var/mobile../videos/1.mp4), however when I wrap the video into the app it works(relative url like: "videos/1.mp4").

On android both works.

Script:

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI("http://some.server.com/download.php");

fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    fileURL,
    function(entry) {
        generateMarkup(entry);
    },
    function(error) {
        handleError(error);
    },
);
```

The generateMarkup() function creates the markup as it recommends by w3c http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="file:///var/mobile/.../movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="file:///var/mobile/.../movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I have written helpers to print out all the files stored inside the app sandbox, so the files are there, the path is correct, but it doesn't play.

Answer (score 0):

After two days of digging found this page: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6051

what helped to figure out that iOS 7.x? can't handle local absolute path in the source element. (Mine: iOS 7.0.4) It just gives a play icon crossed with a line.

This is not working:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="file:///var/mobile/.../movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="file:///var/mobile/.../movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

However this one works finally...

```
<video width="320" height="240" src="file:///var/mobile/.../movie.mp4" controls>
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Hope it helps someone.